# C# class can't see static method of another class

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, static, visibility

I've run into some accessibility problem with one of my Unity projects. I created a class that does NOT inherit from `MonoBehaviour`. It has a method `public static void LoadScene(string sceneName)`.

When I try to call this method from another class, I get a syntax error. This is my first script with the static method:

```
public class GameLoader
{
   public static void LoadScene(string sceneName)
   {
       SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(sceneName);
   }
}
```

And here is my other script:

```
public class GameHandler : MonoBehaviour
{
   private void Start()
   {
       GameLoader.LoadScene("MyScene");    //Syntax error
   }
}
```

Normally, I would have some idea about what might the problem be, but in this case, the `GameHandler` recognizes `GameLoader` as class, but after the dot (`GameLoader.`), it does not find any property or function at all. And I get a syntax error when I try to write anything after the dot.

I experimented a little and it doesn't seem like I would cross another class with the name `GameLoader` and the neccessary namespace was added as well.

I'm pretty lost here, I hope someone can help me out.

Original code`GameLoader`:

```
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine;

namespace MyGame
{
   namespace System
   {
       public class GameLoader
       {
           public static void LoadScene()
           {

           }
       }
   }
}
```

Original `UIHandler`:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;

namespace MyGame
{
   namespace System
   {
       namespace UI
       {
          public class UIHandlerMenu : MonoBehaviour
          {
              GameLoader.LoadScene();
          }
       }
   }
}
```

Error message:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error   IDE1007 The name 'GameLoader.LoadScene' does not exist in the current context.

And the same error for just `LoadScene` itself.

Comment: If you click on the `GameLoader` script in the assets once, do you see its content in the Inspector? Are there any other compiler errors? And do you get the error in Unity or maybe only in your IDE?

Comment: Yes, I see its content and I have no other errors.

Comment: Is GameLoader file saved? Is there a star next to its tab name?

Comment: Everything is saved.

Comment: Are both classes in the same project or is `GameLoader` in a referenced dll/project?

Comment: Same project. And also, I have done the same thing before in THIS project with two other classes and those work.

Comment: This is clearly only a fraction of both codes. Please provide a minimal, complete, verifyable example. Also be precise what compiler error(s) you get. "Can't see" is not a sufficient description. For all we know, the actuall error is some missing semicolon on the other end of your project.

Comment: Okay, the problem is, that I made the dumbest mistake of my programming career so far... I tried to make the call on class level and didn't put it into a method....I must be tired. Thanks everyone for your efforts!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:**
After your edit it is now obvious where the problem lies.
Try moving your call `GameLoader.LoadScene("bla");`  into a method.
If you want this method getting called when instantiating your handler you can move it to a constructor.
Example:

```
public UiHandlerMenu() {
    GameLoader.LoadScene("bla");
}
```

Comment: I even changed from VS 2019 to VS 2017 in Unity and still nothing. Of course Unity and VS restarts didn't really work unfortunately.

Comment: Have you tried removing the code inside of ``` public static void LoadScene(string sceneName) ``` and then cleaning and rebuilding again?

Comment: Yes, I tried it. I even deleted the script file and recreated it. No results.

Comment: If you don't need to instantiate the GameLoader class you can try adding static to the class, otherwise I am out of ideas too: 
public static class GameLoader { ... }

Comment: Tried them already, I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Looking at your edit.. Is GameLoader.LoadScene() really inside the class and not inside of a method/constructor? That is the error

Comment: Oooh, damn I can't believe how dumb this mistake is!!! Thank you very much! In my example code, I put the call into a Start method as it is suppose to be, however in the real code, I was trying to make the call on class level...I'm so sorry for your time!

Comment: It's ok. That's why I am here. Have fun at your project! Btw. I edited my answer, so others know it got solved